# Upload Images to specific folders

Tags: files

how do I upload images (Media) to specific folders inside the default directory? I will have thousands of pictures and would like to have an organized structure of folders.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it D7 or D6 ? You can configure a Directory per content type, go to Edit Content Type and check image related settings.

Comment: Hi, it's D7. hmmm... Each image will be part of the same content type ("photo") so that will not solve my issue. (I have a reference for a content type "gallery" that shows all the "photos" of that gallery). If I could choose a separate folder for each "gallery" would be nice... do you know anything?
Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [File (Field) Paths](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) module. It allows you to automatically sort and rename your uploaded files using token based replacement patterns to maintain a nice clean filesystem.

You can use value of any node field as folder name where files will be uploaded. Or you can create new field for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. This sounds good. I could have a text field in my content type like "upload images to" and then use this value as the path to store the file.

Comment: @Daniel Exactly

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a programmatic solution, you could use the setting array when creating field instance:

```
'settings' => array(
        'file_directory' => 'YOUR_DIRECTORY_HERE',
)
```

For example:

```
 // Create the instance.
    $instance = array(
      'field_name' => $field_name,
      'entity_type' => 'node',
      'bundle' => 'article',
      'label' => 'Article Image',
      'description' => 'An image for the article.',
      'required' => TRUE,
      'settings' => array(
        'file_extensions' => 'png jpg jpeg',
        'file_directory' => 'myModule/news', //your wanted attribute
        'max_filesize' => '20 MB',
        'alt_field' => 1,
        'title_field' => 1,
        'max_resolution' => '300x200',
        'min_resolution' => '200x125',
        'default_image' => 0,
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to upload image in sub directory. their is configuration for drupal image field . Path is your_example_domain.com/admin/structure/types/manage/your_content_type/fields/field_image. you can set the file directory by using token and like static name "your_subdir_name". hope this help!